# Beaglebone Black with MIDI input (via USB) -> can't detect proper port

Tags: port, midi, beagleboneblack, usbserial, qtembedded

A few days back I wrote question regarding MIDI and ALSA, but I've since solved the problem and run into a new one.

the context in short:

*I have a Beaglebone Black with debian 7.5 on it.*

*My host is a 32bit Ubuntu 14.10 installation.*

*I'm using Qt4.8.6 for arm cross-compilation.*

*I am trying create an application which uses a touchscreen and also reads MIDI input from a keyboard. I've used the following tutorial (http://embedded.von-kannen.net/2014/05/21/qt-4-8-6-on-beaglebone-black/) to install Qt embedded so I can crosscompile to my beaglebone (Tutorial needs some fixes, I've got a 'fixed' doc ready if anyone needs one) and the following one to compile ALSA for use on an ARM MPU: omappedia.org/wiki/ALSA_Setup*

Basically after I finally got the program building and deploying onto my beaglebone black it couldn't find the port it needs to receive the MIDI signals.

I'm using a [MidiMate II](http://www.esi-audio.com/products/midimate2/) to connect the MIDI device I'm using to a USB port on a HUB in my Beaglebone Black.

I have the following code to check for available ports (**C++**):

```
RtMidiIn  *midiin = 0;
// RtMidiIn constructor
try {
  midiin = new RtMidiIn();
}
catch ( RtMidiError &error ) {
  error.printMessage();
  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
// Check inputs.
unsigned int nPorts = midiin->getPortCount();
qDebug() << "\nThere are " << nPorts << " MIDI input sources available.\n";
std::string portName;
for ( unsigned int i=0; i<nPorts; i++ ) {
  try {
    portName = midiin->getPortName(i);
  }
  catch ( RtMidiError &error ) {
    error.printMessage();
    delete midiin
  }
  std::cout << "  Input Port #" << i+1 << ": " << portName << '\n';
}
```

I can confirm that the MidiMate functions properly with Ubuntu. As running the application on desktop receives values just fine. I'm not certain of functionality on Debian for the BeagleBone.

The above code tells me there are no available input sources when ran on the Beaglebone, as opposed to the 2 available input sources when ran on both Ubuntu and Windows desktops.

**my question:**
How can I get my Beaglebone to detect the port that I need for reading the live MIDI input?

---

edit:

plugging the midimate into the beaglebone generates a **midi1** entry int the /dev/ list.
however I don't know what and how to do with it.

the RtMidi function I use can only accept an unsigned integer as input so I can't provide the string "midi1" as an argument :(

Comment: Are the ALSA modules like `snd-seq-midi` loaded? Does the device show up in `/proc/asound/seq/clients`?

Comment: There is an entry called II in asound folder.
 
seq is empty.

I don't know how to check whether ALSA modules are loaded :S

the II folder contains: id, midi0, oss_mixed, usbbus, usbid, usbmixer

Answer (score 0):

Your distribution does not load the `snd-seq` and `snd-seq-midi` kernel modules when booting, and has no mechanism to load them on demand either.

Add them to the `/etc/modules` file.

Comment: I added snd-seq and snd-seq-midi to the /etc/modules file. The previously empty /seq folder has stuff in it now. clients contains the following: http://pastebin.com/ymCaVYd6 . However my problem still seems to persist... the program doesn't detect a useful MIDI input source

Comment: I should point out that each of the entries in clients (128 and up) only showed up after running my application.

Comment: Is `snd-usb-audio` loaded (see `lsmod`)?

Comment: it wasn't initially.   
after using `modprobe snd-usb-audio` it shows in the lsmod list.  Problem is not solved :/

Comment: With all three modules loaded, does it show up in `clients`?

Comment: I believe only after the application starts running. I'm at home now so I can't confirm. I can check next monday. Thank you for your help so far.  I thought I read something about getting portaudio serving as a fix (can't seem to trace back the source from home...), however I don't see how it would help considering it's an API of some sort :S. Does having it built provide additional services somehow or would this be a long shot? This whole business is for my internship, which is ending in 2 weeks. This port issue seems to be the last thing getting in my way and I'm eager to get it over with...

Comment: After the modules are loaded, nothing new shows up in `clients`. Here's a screenshot of my terminal with the entries in a variety of files to avoid confusion...: http://imgur.com/u3FRTq8

Comment: Where is the `snd-rawmidi` module? Was it compiled into the kernel? Try unloading and reloading `snd-usb-audio`.

Comment: if try unloading snd-rawmidi it tells me:
`FATAL: Module snd_rawmidi is builtin.`. So I'm guessing it was compiled into the kernel :?
reloading snd_usb_audio doesn't really seem to do anything much...

Comment: I don't know if this is new progression or not. I swapped the cables (MIDImate has 2 midi cables, supposedly for input/output). After swapping them I could `cat /dev/midi1` and receive input from the keyboard (3 Bytes, as it should be the case, so the input is completely valid). The application still does not accept it though. Rather strange since we had previously marked the first cable as being the one that worked when used for desktop. Should I post my code to see if nothing is going wrong there?

Comment: The MIDI driver itself works fine; the problem is that it is not registered correctly with the ALSA sequencer. I suspect this might be related to the partially built-in modules; try recompiling the kernel with all sound drivers as modules.

Comment: How do I do that...? From what I've understood compiling a kernel is no child's play...
Specifically how do I make the sound drivers as modules? It's not a very common thing to do, so information is scarce. I've seen it mentioned a few times but no details on how to do it. I'm looking at an elinux page on compiling kernels and I have no idea what I'm reading... btw, will this cause me to lose the files on the Beaglebone? I'm guessing it's not the case since the kernel is saved in a protected memory area. I'm sorry for my mild incompetence...